# problems with png8 and wmts

Tags: qgis, wmts

I have published a WMTS based on png8 images. 
I have tried to view it in QGIS but even though I can apparently connect to the service I see no image at the viewer.

I am not sure whether the image format must be described in the capabilities as png or png8. 
Should the image format be described as png or png8?
does QGIS support png8 format for WMTS?

Comment: what does your getCapabilities response say the mime type is?

Comment: <Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>

Comment: http://sig.pamplona.es/ogc/wmts/1.0.0/wmtsCapabilities.xml

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this issue, I'm afraid.

I added `png8` as an output format in GeoServer for the topp:states layer and added my local GeoServer to QGIS as a WMTS layer (http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities). I could then add the layer to my map as both `png` and `png8` as expected (Using the pop out browser from the `add dataset button`). QGIS is making requests like  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=topp:states&STYLE=&FORMAT=image/png8&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:3&TILEROW=2&TILECOL=4
which work fine for me.

Oddly, in QGIS 3.2, I don't see the new format in the list from the browser tab and if I click refresh to update the view then QGIS crashes!

**EDIT**

So looking at your capabilities the main difference is that it is a RESTful rather than KVP service but QGIS should be able to handle this. I can add your service to QGIS but it doesn't seem to make any requests after  `http://sig.pamplona.es/ogc/wmts/1.0.0/wmtsCapabilities.xml?`
 which is successful.

Just to try something different I tried to pull your server into my GeoServer and it fails saying "WMTS Connection test failed: No good Bbox found for layer carto1998" - so may be you need to check those, it might be expecting a lat/lon bounding box.